# Remove site name from the button href until the " ? " symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following button on my website:

```
   <a role="button" id="purchase" href="https://www.website.com/my-product/?add-to-cart=111&variation_id=115855/">
```

This button belongs to selector so when user choose another product option the variation changes dynamically.

As an example, user can choose the variation A, B, C

And the button changes into something like that:

```
For A - https://www.website.com/my-product/?add-to-cart=111&variation_id=115856/

For B - https://www.website.com/my-product/?add-to-cart=111&variation_id=115857/

For C - https://www.website.com/my-product/?add-to-cart=111&variation_id=115858/
```

All I want is to exclude everything until the " **?** " symbol in the button link and it should looks like that when I hover on it:

```
<a role="button" id="purchase" href="?add-to-cart=111&variation_id=115855/">
```

I tried something like that:

```
function removeSlug() {

  var slugtest = document.getElementById("purchase").value;
  text.split('?')[0];
}
```

but nothing helped. Unfortunately my js knowledge is too bad to get where the issue is.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Cant you put the links like this in the HTML from the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.setAttribute(](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)) and [.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) plus array [.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop):

```js
var slugtest = '?' + document.getElementById("purchase").getAttribute('href')
                                                           .split('?').pop();
document.getElementById("purchase").setAttribute('href', slugtest);

console.log(document.getElementById("purchase"));
```

```html
<a role="button" id="purchase" href="https://www.website.com/my-product/?add-to-cart=111&variation_id=115855/">
```

Another way to change an url can be based on [URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL):

```js
// get the href value
var hreftext = document.getElementById("purchase").getAttribute('href');

// convert href to an URL and get the search property
var slugtest = new URL(hreftext).search;
document.getElementById("purchase").setAttribute('href', slugtest);

console.log(document.getElementById("purchase"));
```

```html
<a role="button" id="purchase" href="https://www.website.com/my-product/?add-to-cart=111&variation_id=115855/">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `document.getElementById("purchase").value` since it is not an input field but an element, you have to use `.getAttribute("href")` like this

```
var slugtest = document.getElementById("purchase").getAttribute("href");
console.log(slugtest.split("?")[1]);
```

You can run it in the snippet below:

```html
<a role="button" id="purchase" href="https://www.website.com/my-product/?add-to-cart=111&variation_id=115855/">

<script>
    var slugtest = document.getElementById("purchase").getAttribute("href");
    console.log(slugtest.split("?")[1]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a solution using regex.

```
function modifyLinkHref() {
  var href = document.getElementById("purchase").getAttribute('href');
  var newHref = href.replace(/(.*)(\?.*)/g, "$2");
  document.getElementById("purchase").setAttribute('href', newHref);
  console.log(document.getElementById("purchase").getAttribute("href"));
}

modifyLinkHref();
```

Regex:

```
(.*)(\?.*)
```

Details:

- `.*`: Group 1 - take any character until before character ?
- `\?.*`: Group 2 - after character ?, take any character

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/JbRTOO/1)

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w2qbv0rj/18/)